# Python function to calculate a median without mean in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, median

I have a big Dataframe (about 3GB) and I want to calcul a sort of median on a group by on few columns but i don't want to take the mean of the two central elements when i have an even number of values but get the lowest of this two values.
I know how to do a normal median, here is an example to reproduce my issue :

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'idx':  [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5],
        'value': [5,12,7,8,10,3,8,4,6,1,19,5,10,12,3,8,14]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['idx','value'])
df['median']=df.groupby(['idx'])['value'].transform(np.median)
print(df)

    idx  value  median
0     1    5.0     8.0
1     1   12.0     8.0
2     1    7.0     8.0
3     1    8.0     8.0
4     1   10.0     8.0
5     2    3.0     5.0
6     2    8.0     5.0
7     2    4.0     5.0
8     2    6.0     5.0
9     2    1.0     5.0
10    2   19.0     5.0
11    3    5.0    10.0
12    3   10.0    10.0
13    3   12.0    10.0
14    4    3.0     5.5
15    4    8.0     5.5
16    5   14.0    14.0
```

But as i said i do not want to have this result.

I want  :

- for idx=2 we have 1,3,4,6,8,19 so with median i get (4+6)/2 -> 5 but
  i want min(4,6) -> 4
- for idx=4 we have 3,8 so with median i get (3+8)/2 -> 5.5 but i want
  min(3,8) -> 3

I can do this whith the function below but the performance is very low :

```
def calcul_median(x):
    a=x['values'].values.tolist()
    if len(a)%2==1:
        a = np.median(a)
    elif len(a)==0:
        a=0
    else:
        a.sort()
        a =a[int((len(a)/2)-1)]
    x['median'] =a
    return x

df2=df.groupby(['idx']).apply(calcul_median)
```

This function works but it is very slow (50 times slower than median).

**EDIT**

The function statistics.median_low do that but that is also slow.
3s with numpy vs 52s with statistics.

I have try another function  with argpartition

```
def calcul_tps_medianv2(x):
    a=x['dureetrajet'].values.tolist()
    if len(a)%2==1:
        a = np.median(a)
    elif len(a)==0:
        a=0
    else:
        a[np.argpartition(a,int((len(a)/2)-1))[int((len(a)/2)-1)]]
    x['median'] =a
    return x
```

But that is slower than with the statistics solution.

Have you any idea to speed up this function or any other idea ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The standard library contains a [`median_low()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median_low) that does just that.

Comment: Thanks Tim ! That's work well on my example, i will try it on my entire dataframe

Comment: I just try it on my entire df that takes 3s with numpy.median but 52s with statistics.median_low()

Comment: I guess that can’t be avoided. Calling an external function will surely be much slower than a built-in pandas method...

Comment: Maybe you could try argpartition instead of sorting the entire array in your own function.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html#numpy.argpartition

Comment: I just try with argpartition but that is slower than with statistics.median_low(). That takes few minutes (still running). May be i do it wrong.

Comment: I only know one single way to have a custom function to be as fast as a numpy one: compile it in Cython to make it a ufunc...